# Cannot update one field at a time with VSTO for Word

Tags: ms-word, vsto, field, updating

When fields are nested, there is a problem.

```
foreach (Word.Field field in this.Application.ActiveDocument.Fields)
        {
            field.Update();
            text = field.Result.Text;

        }
```

The above code does not work.

The process starts, but winds up in an endless loop or some other process that hangs the system.

Thinking about it, I can surmise that when you update a field, it might have an effect on the fields collection - thus, the loop fails.

Does anyone have any ideas on implementing this?

P.S.   I know there is a Document.UpdateFields() method to update ALL fields.   However, there are reasons why I cannot use this and need to only update specific field types.

My apologies!  I was going to give an example of a nested field but was trying to test some more before sending anyone (Jack) on a goose-chase.

I waited and waited and waited, and after a good 2 or 3 minutes, it finished.   After the last field, it crashed with this message:

Object has been deleted.

The error was generated from the following line inside the loop:

string text = field.Code.Text;

The template is being tested on mergefields that are not being found because I am testing without database connectivity.   It would be odd, but explainable, that it goes through all the fields and then, at the end of the day, the very OUTER IF field's result is "Error!  Reference source not found."  But I still don't get why this could happen.

Nor do I understand why looping takes 3 minutes while a call to document.Fields.Update() will do the same thing in about 1 second and NOT result in the error described above.

Again, my apologies.   I never considered updating inside a loop would be vastly slower that a call to doc.fields.update().

Comment: Can you give example of a nested field? I wasn't able to trigger a problem with your code and something like { AUTHOR {FILENAME }}   also tried { MacroButton "FollowLink"{HYPERLINK "http://www.stackoverflow.com" }}

Comment: On hunch, instead of a foreach loop over the collection, try a for loop using an index.

Comment: Hi, Jack.   I tried the index - for(x=1, x<fields.count, x++).   It did not work, either.   I am going to edit the main post to show you what I mean about nested fields.

Comment: I might be pushing it, but a backwards loop, maybe?

Comment: I'd still need a way to reproduce the error. If I can recreate it, it would mean a bug in my own code, too, so I would try to fix.

Comment: I see.   Well, there might not be a bug in your code.   As I said, I was using Mergfields and testing without a data connection.   So, my outer-most IF expression will ultimately result in "Error!   Data Source Not Found."   If you want to try to reproduce, then, I would say to make your outer-most IF field fail to find the replacement text it needs.   Then, at the end of the loop, you might find the error I got.